# What is "normal" severity in Allure reporter?

Tags: bug-severity, allure

Sorry English is not my first language.

From what I read, defect severity is defined in 4 level in general.

- Critical S1
- Major S2
- Low S3
- Trivial S4

Allure reporter defines severity in 5 level.

- Blocker
- Critical
- Normal
- Minor
- Trivial

Since I have no idea how to modify severity level in Allure reporter, I want to equalize these term to be used in Allure.

I'm thinking to make

- Critical S1 = Allure Blocker
- Major S2 = Allure Critical
- Minor S3 = Allure Minor
- Trivial S4 = Allure Trivial

But, this will leave "normal" column empty in bar chart. What even is "normal" severity in Allure?

Comment: Severity is just a label, normal is just the default for unlabelled tests (see e.g. https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_severity_4).

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I think it's much more important to see a definition of severity levels. From what I know, different systems and defect management tools define different levels - in terms of names or even in terms of how many they define. Therefore, knowing at least a one-sentence description of what they mean seems important to me.

For example, we use severity level *"Medium"*, which means *"Has the potential to affect progress."* If you're able to find something like this, it may make much more sense. Otherwise, *"normal"* doesn't really say much.

Comment: Ok. So, it is subjective. 

Could you give me some examples of "medium" severity case?

Comment: We use the level for problems that could affect progress of a user. but there's a workaround at the same time. However, be careful when adopting levels from other projects. And also read what @jonrsharpe posted in comments, it seems that "normal" is (also) used as a default level and/or fallback if a severity level is not set correctly.